# GitHub - Como aceitar PR automaticamente após revisões?

Tags: git, github, revisão-de-código, código-aberto

Estou realizando um projeto no GitHub e gostaria de estruturar algo que após uma quantidade determinada de aprovações na revisão, que ocorresse o merge do pull request de forma automática.

Sei que isso é possível, pois já ouvi falar desse processo em algumas ferramentas como o GitLab pago. Além disso, com o GitHub Actions algumas automações têm se tornado realidade.

Já tentei procurar em alguns links próprios do GitHub, mas o máximo que encontrei foi isso: https://docs.github.com/pt/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request
, mas nada explicito quanto ao número de aprovações.